# visual studio android emulator install google service error "cp: /data/local/tmp/.flash_tmp/system/*: No such file or directory"

Tags: android-emulator

I am trying to install google play service to visual studio emulator. After drag & drop the zip file to the emulator, the installation failed with message in the log file "`cp: /data/local/tmp/.flash_tmp/system/`*: No such file or directory".

The same error occurred with simply drag & drop the zip file to the emulator or manual adb install. Both Kitkat & Marshmallow VM (using zip for the corresponding android version) got the same error too.

Is there any thing missing in my visual studio installation?

[Emulator screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFsXb.png)

The error log:

---

Installing flashable ZIP file '/sdcard/open_gapps-x86-4.4-nano-20160723.zip'

Unpacking archive `'/sdcard/open_gapps-x86-4.4-nano-20160723.zip' to '/data/local/tmp/.flash_tmp'`

extracting: Core/defaultetc-common.tar.xz

extracting: Core/defaultframework-common.tar.xz

.....

.....

extracting: META-INF/CERT.SF

extracting: META-INF/CERT.RSA

Installing file '/system/*'

```
cp: /data/local/tmp/.flash_tmp/system/*: No such file or directory
```

Could not copy '`/data/local/tmp/.flash_tmp/system/*' to '/system/`*'

---

Answer (score 12):

you should download the right package for your emulator , 
i had the same solution , i tried to install  open_gapps-arm64-6.0-mini.zip – and open_gapps-arm-6.0-mini.zip but none of these installed , downloaded gapps-600-base-20151016-1-signed.zip ( http://www.devfiles.co/download/m4Er5IlQ/gapps-600-base-20151016-1-signed.zip ) and it worked via drag and drop .

check for right version in here : http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/

Comment: Hi Reza, for future reference how did you know which was the 'right package' for the VS emulators? That's a very long list, and the one you mention doesn't give any indication it works with VS emulators or even works with x86 at all (although you're right - it does work).

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. The file downloaded from opengapps worked in other vm but not the visual studio emulator. File from http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/ works.

Comment: I got mine from teamandroid.com but unfortunately got the same error